# values in LinkedList changed outside of the function, clone() a 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, linked-list

If I try to read from the LinkedList “solvedBords”outside the solve function all values in the 2d array “board” that is saved in solvedBords turns to 0.

but in the “solved” function all values in the in the 2d array “board” that is saved in solvedBords is entirely accurate.

Is this is due to recursion? Any explanation would be appreciated

main class

```
public class main {

   public static void main(String[] arg){
      testQueen N = new testQueen();
   }
}
```

test class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class testQueen {

    private int[][] board;
    private LinkedList<int[][]> solvedBords = new LinkedList<>();
    private static int boardSize = 0;

    testQueen() {
        boardSize = 8;
        board = new int[boardSize][boardSize];
        start();
    }

    void start() {

        solve(0);

        System.out.println("solvedBords = " + solvedBords.size());
        while (!solvedBords.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("this is in the start funktion");
            printBord(solvedBords.pop());
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    void solve(int row) {

        if (row == boardSize) {
            System.out.println("this is in the solve function: ");
            printBord(board);
            System.out.println("");
            solvedBords.add(board.clone()); // 2d array “board” that is saved in
                                            // solvedBords
            /*
             * System.out.println("solvedBords = " + solvedBords.size());
             * while(!solvedBords.isEmpty()){ printBord(solvedBords.pop());
             * System.out.println(""); }
             */
            return;
        }

        for (int colum = 0; colum < boardSize; colum++) {
            if (validMove(row, colum)) {
                paceQueen(row, colum, 0);
                solve(row + 1);
                paceQueen(row, colum, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    boolean validMove(int x, int y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
            if (get(x, i) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            if (get(i, y) > 0) {
                return false;
            }

            if (get(x - i, y - i) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            if (get(x - i, y + i) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            if (get(x + i, y - i) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            if (get(x + i, y + i) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     *
     * if type == 1 the queen is going to be placed in row x and column y
     *
     * else if type == 0 the queen is going to be removed from row x column y
     *
     * @param x
     *            is the row
     * @param y
     *            is the column
     * @param type
     *            is 0 or 1
     */
    void paceQueen(int x, int y, int type) {
        if (type == 0) {
            board[x][y] = 1;
        } else if (type == 1) {
            board[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }

    int get(int x, int y) {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= boardSize || y >= boardSize) {
            return -1;
        }
        return board[x][y];
    }

    void printBord(int[][] board) {

        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] > 0) {
                    System.out.print("[1]");
                } else if (board[i][j] == 0) {
                    System.out.print("[0]");
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?

Comment: tried to fix the best I could, having trouble pasting my code.

Comment: Your post is not readable, please use punctuation and proper grammar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you can't use `clone()` with 2D arrays.

In Java, `int[][] board` is **not** really a 2D array or matrix - it is a 1D array of 1D arrays. In other words, `board` is an array of object references, where each object is an 1D `int[]` array. When you call `clone()` on an `array[][]` it performs a *shallow copy* - the outer array is cloned, but the inner arrays are not - they are just new references to the same data. The upshot of this is that every time you change values in `board` you are changing everything in `solvedBoards` as well.

One solution is to write a deep copy function `clone2dArray` and replace your call to `clone()` with `clone2dArray()`:

```
int[][] clone2dArray(int[][] original) {
    int [][] cloned = new int[original.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
        cloned[i] = original[i].clone();
    }
    return cloned;
}

void solve(int row) {
    ...
    solvedBords.add(clone2dArray(board)); // 2d array “board” that is saved 
    ...
}
```

Another, perhaps better, solution might be to create a matrix class to store your board.

Also be aware that you are recursively calling `solve()` and when you return from the call, `board` will have changed. This might not be what you are expecting. You could instead pass `board` in as a parameter to `solve`, making sure you always pass it in as a `clone2dArray()` copy. The would ensure that `board` is not changed when you return from a recursive call.